# Load webview while clicking on a textview

Tags: android, android-webview

I want to load a `WebView` while clicking on a `TextView` from my app in Android. What should I do?

I have tried this one:

```
//Get a reference to your WebView//
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//Specify the URL you want to display// 
webView.loadUrl("https://example.com");
```

And the xml code is:

```
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/weblink"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:linksClickable="true"
    android:text="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    android:textColor="@color/blue"
    android:textColorLink="@color/blue"
    />
```

But it is not working properly. The `TextView` with id "weblink" is the specified `TextView`.

Comment: simply call webView.loadUrl("https://example.com"); on click event of textview

Comment: Is I need to create a new activity and xml layout page to load the `webview` .Here I have used the same layout for loading the webview

Comment: Try then intent .Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(i);

Comment: Thank you all for supporting me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like the below code :

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
TextView weblink=findElementById(R.id.weblink);
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    weblink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            webView.loadUrl("https://example.com");
        }
    });
```

Comment: I got the `webview`.But, it not came in correct format.May be it not be responsive.Can you help me

Comment: Can you post the output I mean the screenshot.

Comment: See my Edited answer.

Comment: Then try with some website which is responsive

Comment: Your answer helped me to load the webview.So I accept your answer

Comment: Thanks! If you found the way post here.

Comment: Ok. I will post here if  I got it.

Comment: Solved the responsiveness problem.Please check the link https://capdroid.wordpress.com/2014/08/07/resizing-webview-to-match-the-content-size/

Comment: Interesting solution

Answer (score -1):

```
  public static void setDescriptionWebView(final Context context, final String description, final WebView mWebView) {
    try {
        mWebView.setFocusableInTouchMode(FALSE);
        mWebView.setFocusable(FALSE);
        mWebView.getSettings().setDefaultTextEncodingName("UTF-8");

        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        Resources res = context.getResources();
        final int fontSize = res.getInteger(R.integer.font_size);
        webSettings.setDefaultFontSize(fontSize);

        final String mimeType = "text/html; charset=UTF-8";
        final String encoding = "utf-8";
        final String rtl = new SessionManager(context).isRTLOn() ? "dir=\"rtl\"" : "";

        final String text = "<html><head>"+

                "<style type=\"text/css\">" +
                "@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) { " +
                "body { background-color: transparent; color: white; } " +
                "table, th, td { border:1px solid black; }" +
                "table { border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; }" +
                "th, td { text-align: left; padding: 8px; border: 1px solid;}" +
                "}" +

                "@media (prefers-color-scheme: light) { " +
                "body { background-color: transparent; color: black;  } " +
                "table, th, td { border:1px solid black; }" +
                "table { border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; }" +
                "th, td { text-align: left; padding: 8px; border: 1px solid;}" +
                "}" +

                "</style>" +
                "</head><body " + rtl + ">" + description + "</body></html>";

        mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, text, mimeType, encoding, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Utils.getErrors(e);
    }
}
```